# rails models doesn't find an attribute in seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've met little unpredictable behaviour of rails `db:seed`.

I have a model, which has a `status` attribute.

```
class Task
  enum status: { todo: 0, awaiting: 1, starting: 2, pending: 3, ending: 4, done: 5, waste: 6 }
```

If I check the `Task` at the console, I see the `status` field.

```
=> Task(id: integer, title: string, status: integer)
```

But if I raise Task model (`raise Task.inspect`) at the seed, I get just

```
=> Task(id: integer, title: string)
```

Without `status`. Why status attribute is missing just in this model just in `seeds`? Any ideas?

**Exception**:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `status`
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by *if I raise Task at the seed*?

Answer (score 0):

You should define this attribute as an **attr_accessor** attribute in you model.

Maybe this post will be useful: http://rubyinrails.com/2014/03/17/what-is-attr_accessor-in-rails/

Comment: Omg, why should I do that? `ActiveRecord enum` method defines attr_acessors for me

Comment: Well, maybe you should ask yourself **"why do I want a not persisted attribute in the seeds task?"**.  Seeds, as its name says, is something concerned about Database, so maybe what you want is to make it persistant

Comment: I've asked just "why rails behaves unpredictable"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `enum` in seed, try this `status: Task::status['todo']`